# Intuition behind Gaussian distribution in $N$ dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, probability

In N dimensional space, given the following Gaussian distribution:

$$p(x) = \frac{1}{(2*\pi*\sigma^2)^{D/2}} \exp{\left(-\frac{||x||^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}$$

Let's convert x to the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$. The probability mass concentrates between $\sqrt{d}$ and $\sqrt{d} + 3$. However, $p(r = 0)$ is larger than $p(r = \sqrt{d})$.

Why doesn't the probability mass concentrate around $r = 0$ (where $p(r)$ is maximum)?

Comment: Because the volume around $0$ is much smaller than the volume around a sphere of larger radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have used $N$, $D$ and $d$ to represent the dimension and your later comments seem to assume $\sigma^2=1$.

If the dimension is $2$ or more, then after your move to polar co-ordinates (not just $\theta$ when $d \gt 2$) and implicit integration over direction to get the marginal density $p(r)$ for the Euclidean distance $r$ from the origin, then this gives the [chi-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) (square-root of $\chi^2$) with the density $p(0)=0$.   The mode for the radius is actually $\sqrt{d-1}$.

If you had not implicitly integrated over direction, then the mode of the distribution would be at the origin.  But integrating over direction gives shells of hyperspheres, and these are larger for larger radii.